# Remove Headers Added By WebServer (nginx) In Aspcore Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, nginx, webserver

I am using aspcore sdk3.1, when I published my application on nginx without any configuration in My App, I saw that the web server automatically added 1access-control-allow-origin:*1 Header to all my requests.

Can I delete this header in my application And Add My Own Allow-Origin Header? , because I do not have access to the web server settings

Answer (score 0):

If nginx adds the CORS allow all origin header, then there must be some configuration like [this one here](https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html)

```
#
# Wide-open CORS config for nginx
#
location / {
     if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        #
        # Om nom nom cookies
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        #
        # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
        #
        # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
     }
     if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
     }
     if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
     }
}
```

- Just remove the `add_header` lines wherever you don't want them and you'll be fine.
- Beware that you don't change all the applications, someone else might be using it, so configure for your location only.
- If you don't have access, then just liase with the administrator to make you a new configuration for the application.

It seems that https://serverfault.com/questions/751678/how-can-i-replace-access-control-allow-origin-header-in-proxy-response-with-ngin/927668#927668 add header will override the one added to the request by net-core configuration, so you seem to be out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

http {

```
##
# Basic Settings
##

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
# server_tokens off;

# server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# SSL Settings
##

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;

#proxy_cache_path  /data/nginx/cache  levels=1:2    keys_zone=STATIC:10m
#inactive=14d  max_size=10g;

upstream dotnet {
    zone dotnet 64k;
    server 0.0.0.0:5005;
} 

# gzip_vary on;
# gzip_proxied any;
# gzip_comp_level 6;
# gzip_buffers 16 8k;
# gzip_http_version 1.1;
# gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

}

This IS  My Config Code  Whats Wrong?